# Does using ConcurrentDictionary TryGetValue within an if statement make the if contents thread-safe?

Tags: c#, concurrency

If I have a ConcurrentDictionary and use the TryGetValue within an if statement, does this make the if statement's contents thread safe? Or must you lock still within the if statement?

Example:

```
        ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Client> m_Clients;

        Client client;
        //Does this if make the contents within it thread-safe? 
        if (m_Clients.TryGetValue(clientGUID, out client))
        {
            //Users is a list.
            client.Users.Add(item);
        }
```

or do I have to do:

```
        ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Client> m_Clients;

        Client client;
        //Does this if make the contents within it thread-safe? 
        if (m_Clients.TryGetValue(clientGUID, out client))
        {
            lock (client)
            {
                //Users is a list.
                client.Users.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `TryGetValue` itself is thread-safe... it does not make the `if` statement thread-safe... in the example your show you need the `lock`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I have seen a bunch of examples that use an object like this for locking: private readonly object m_lock = new object(); . Can i lock the way I did, or should I use the object for locking?

Comment: that depends on what you want to achieve - if you want to make sure that the instace of `client` is only modified by one thread then use your current approach... the other approach can be implemented to even serialize changes globally for example...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you have to lock inside the if statement the only guarantee you get from concurrent dictionary is that its methods are thread save.

Comment: Thanks, one more follow up question: I have seen a bunch of examples that use an object like this for locking: private readonly object m_lock = new object(); . Can i lock the way I did, or should I use the object for locking?

Comment: the recommended way is to lock with a new object. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks again. For understanding: If I use the readonly object method for locking. And then I lock in 2 different methods within the same object and both methods are called on the same instance from different threads. Then, will the 2 methods have contention? Should I be using 2 readonly lock objects, 1 per method?

Comment: the `m_lock` object is an identifier of a lock so all lock statements that share the same `m_lock` instance will be protected from concurrent execution. You can choose where you want to declare this object (class level method or even some other class as public readonly field) and if it is static or not. It depends on the code intention. As a general rule try to minimize scope an count of such objects - usually private field is what you need.

Comment: I suggest you don't expose the Client's users collection and let each Client be responsible for being thread safe. E.g. add an AddUser method to it that is thread safe.

Comment: Thanks Rafal, you have helped me greatly :). Cheers!

Comment: should be "methods are thread safe" and not as it is now "thread save" i guess )

Answer (score 3):

While both of the current answers are technically true I think that the potential exists for them to be a little misleading and they don't express ConcurrentDictionary's big strengths.  Maybe the OP's original way of solving the problem with locks worked in that specific circumstance but this answer is aimed more generally towards people learning about ConcurrentDictionary for the first time.

Concurrent Dictionary is designed so that you don't *have* to use locks.  It has several specialty methods designed around the idea that some other thread could modify the object in the dictionary while you're currently working on it.  For a simple example, the TryUpdate method lets you check to see if a key's value has changed between when you got it and the moment that you're trying to update it.  If the value that you've got matches the value currently in the ConcurrentDictionary you can update it and TryUpdate returns true.  If not, TryUpdate returns false.  The [documentation for the TryUpdate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryupdate?view=net-5.0) can make this a little confusing because it doesn't make it explicitly clear why there is a comparison value but that's the idea behind the comparison value.  If you wanted to have a little more control around adding or updating, you could use one of the overloads of the [AddOrUpdate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=net-5.0) to either add a value for a key if it doesn't exist at the moment that you're trying to add it or update the value if some other thread has already added a value for the key that is specified.  The context of whatever you're trying to do will dictate the appropriate method to use.  The point is that, rather than locking, try taking a look at the specialty methods that ConcurrentDictionary provides and prefer those over trying to come up with your own locking solution.

In the case of OP's original question, I would suggest that instead of this:

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Client> m_Clients;

    Client client;
    //Does this if make the contents within it thread-safe? 
    if (m_Clients.TryGetValue(clientGUID, out client))
    {
        //Users is a list.
        client.Users.Add(item);
    }
```

One might try the following instead*:

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Client> m_Clients;

    Client originalClient;
    if(m_Clients.TryGetValue(clientGUID, out originalClient)
    {
        //The Client object will need to implement IEquatable if more
        //than an object instance comparison needs to be done.  This
        //sample code assumes that Client implements IEquatable.

        //If copying a Client is not trivial, you'll probably want to
        //also implement a simple type of copy in a method of the Client
        //object.  This sample code assumes that the Client object has
        //a ShallowCopy method to do this copy for simplicity's sake.
        Client modifiedClient = originalClient.ShallowCopy();

        //Make whatever modifications to modifiedClient that need to get
        //made...
        modifiedClient.Users.Add(item);
        
        //Now update the value in the ConcurrentDictionary
        if(!m_Clients.TryUpdate(clientGuid, modifiedClient, originalClient))
        {
            //Do something if the Client object was updated in between
            //when it was retrieved and when the code here tries to
            //modify it.
        }
    }
```

*Note in the example above, I'm using TryUpate for ease of demonstrating the concept.  In practice, if you need to make sure that an object gets added if it doesn't exist or updated if it does, the AddOrUpdate method would be the ideal option because the method handles all of the looping required to check for add vs update and take the appropriate action.

It might seem like it's a little harder at first because it may be necessary to implement IEquatable and, depending on how instances of Client need to be copied, some sort of copying functionality but it pays off in the long run if you're working with ConcurrentDictionary and objects within it in any serious way.

Comment: I think that what you are suggesting is to make the `Client` class freezable, so that it becomes immutable after it has been entered into the `ConcurrentDictionary`. You could probably communicate it clearer by adding the line `modifiedClient.Freeze();` after the line `modifiedClient.Users.Add(item);`. Alternatively you could have a `ClientBuilder` class with a `ToImmutable()` method, that returns an immutable `Client`. Although this architecture is valid, it's probably too cumbersome for casual applications IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks for the feedback.  The main thing that I was trying to show was the use of a comparison value when using the TryUpdate method.  I chose to use the TryUpdate method rather that something like AddOrUpdate because it seemed like a simpler option to explain and give an example for.  The Client class doesn't so much have to be immutable but one would need an "original" copy of it, pre-modification, so that one has something to compare it against when doing the update.  In your opinion, what would be a clearer way of showing that?

Comment: Given that in case the `TryUpdate` fails, the code should try again to update the `ConcurrentDictionary` with a new `originalClient.ShallowCopy()` (or probably a `.DeepCopy()` for real thread-safety), in other words given that the `TryGetValue`/`TryUpdate` combo should be enclosed in a `while` loop, probably the `AddOrUpdate` would be a more practical example because it does this looping internally. You could consider adding a note that the `TryGetValue`/`TryUpdate` example serves more educational/illustration purposes, than showing how to deal with this kind of situations in practice.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer could be misleading, depending on your point of view and the scope of thread safety you are trying to achieve. This answer is aimed at people who stumble on this question while learning about threading and concurrency:

It's true that locking on the output of the dictionary retrieval (the Client object) makes *some* of the code thread safe, but *only the code that is accessing that retrieved object within the lock.* In the example, it's possible that another thread *removes* that object from the dictionary *after* the current thread retrieves it. (Even though there are no statements between the retrieval and the lock, other threads can still execute in between.) Then, this code would add the Client object to the Users list even though it is no longer in the concurrent dictionary. That could cause an exception, synchronization, or race condition.

It depends on what the rest of the program is doing. But in the scenario I'm describing, it would be safer to put the lock around the entire dictionary retrieval. And then a regular dictionary might be faster and simpler than a concurrent dictionary, as long as you always lock on it while using it!

Comment: I wouldn't lock code around usage of a ConcurrentDictionary until I'm sure I have to. The ConcurrentDictionary already is thread-safe. It doesn't make much sense to me to lock manually and use the normal dictionary as an alternative. Your example with deleting an object after something else retrieved it is no real problem. If it would be you had to mark it as undeletable. A problem would be to get an object from the dictionary after it was deleted. Fortunately impossible in .net- :)